# CORS issue while uploading files from my admin application to S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless

I was facing a cors issue when i upload any file from my admin application where API is in lambda (US-EAST-1) to S3 bucket which is in (US-WEST-2) region .
I have edited my CORS policy as

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "PUT",
        "POST",
        "DELETE"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
}
```

]

and my bucket policy is

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicRead",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
    }
]
```

}

May I know why i was getting this issue